# Randomly generated world for text-based RPG

Tags: python, object-oriented, role-playing-game

I am developing a text-based RPG with a randomly generated world space. I have built a light engine to produce a world for me and fill it with 'world objects' like trees, mountains, villages, and the like. The world can be generated either through a fully automatic method, or a "manual" method, that allows for more specific placement of world objects.

My code might be a bit sloppy, since I'm rather new to Python programming and the world of OOP. That being said, the following code provides the complete `WorldSpace` class, but a rather bare-bones version on the `Player` class -- a version that just specifies some basic variables to show how I will be structuring the real `Player` class.

I believe all of this code to be in working condition. My apologies if any of you get errors.

```
from random import randint, choice, randrange
```

Player class:

```
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.baseStats = {'health': 1, 'stamina': 0, 'mana': 0, 'equip load': 0,
        'level': 1}

        self.descStats = {'name': None, 'race': None, 'class': None,
        'description': None}

        self.baseSkills = {'strength': 0, 'intelligence': 0, 'defense': 0,
        'speech': 0, 'endurance': 0, 'faith': 0, 'luck': 0}

        self.inventory = {'weapons': [], 'armor sets': [], 'rings': [],
        'miracles': [], 'spells': [], 'gold': None, 'keys': None}

        self.equipment = {'weapon': None, 'armor set': None, 'rings': []}

    def moveNorth(self):
        self.x -= 1

    def moveSouth(self):
        self.x += 1

    def moveEast(self):
        self.y += 1

    def moveWest(self):
        self.y -= 1

    def movement(self, world):
        movement_inp = raw_input("""
W. | Move North
S. | Move South
D. | Move East
A. | Move West
> """).lower()
        if movement_inp == 'w':
            self.moveNorth()

        elif movement_inp == 's':
            self.moveSouth()

        elif movement_inp == 'd':
            self.moveEast()

        elif movement_inp == 'a':
            self.moveWest()

        else:
            print 'Not a valid command'
            self.movement(world)

hero = Player(1, 2)
```

World class:

```
class WorldSpace(object):
    world_object_list = ['forest', 'mountain', 'ocean', 'other']

    def __init__(self, row, col, world_array):
        self.row = row  # Number of lists to be created.
        self.col = col  # Number of indexes inside of each row.
        self.world_array = world_array

    def genSingle_Char(self, char, count):
        # 'genSingle_Char' - Generate single character world objects.
        # Adds a number of random, specific characters to the world array.
        original_count = count
        while count != 0:
            row = randrange(len(self.world_array))
            column = randrange(len(self.world_array[0]))
            if self.world_array[row][column] == ' ':
                self.world_array[row][column] = char
                count -= 1

        print 'Generated {} {}\'s...'.format(original_count, char)

    def genLine_WObj(self, a, b, row_val, char, count):
        # 'genLine_WObj' - Generate Line(like) world object.
        # Used to place lines of psuedo-random width and length onto the world map.
        while count != 0:
            row_col_dict = {row_val: (a, b)}
            for row in row_col_dict.keys():
                startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

                for i in range(startPos, endPos):
                    self.world_array[row][i] = char

            b += choice([0, 0, 1])
            a += choice([0, 0, 0, 1])

            row_val -= 1
            count -= 1

        print 'Generated psuedo-randomized line with world object `{}`'.format(char)

    def genShiftBlock(self, a, b, row_val, char, count):
        while count != 0:
            row_col_dict = {row_val: (a, b)}
            for row in row_col_dict.keys():
                startPos, endPos = row_col_dict[row]

                for i in range(startPos, endPos):
                    self.world_array[row][i] = char

                a += choice([0, 1, -1])
                b += choice([0, 1, -1])
                row_val -= 1
                count -= 1

        print 'Generated shift block(`~` | oceans).'

    def printPlayerMap(self):
        print('\n'.join([''.join(['{:1}'.format(item) for item in row])
                for row in self.world_array]))

    @classmethod
    def generateWorld(cls, autogen):
        print 'Starting world generation...'
        print
        if autogen is True:
            row_amt = 35
            col_amt = 75

        else:
            print 'Recommended row amt: 35, recommended col amt: 75.'
            print
            row_amt = input('Please specify row length of world array.: ')
            col_amt = input('Please specify column length of world array.: ')
            if (row_amt or col_amt) == 0:
                print 'Invalid world values!'
                self.generateWorld(False)

        world_array = [[' ']*col_amt for _ in xrange(row_amt)]
        print 'Created world...'
        return WorldSpace(row_amt, col_amt, world_array)

    def autoModifyWorld(self):
        print 'Now automatically modifying the world space.'
        # Forests:
        count = randint(1, 4)
        while count != 0:
            a_val_rand = choice([randint(10, 20), randint(45, 50)])
            b_val_rand = a_val_rand + randint(5, 10)
            row_val_rand = randint(10, 30)
            count_val_rand = randint(4, 8)
            self.genLine_WObj(a_val_rand, b_val_rand, row_val_rand, 't',
            count_val_rand)
            count -= 1

        print 'Created forests...'

        # Mountains:
        a_val_rand = choice([randint(22, 23), randint(45, 46)])
        b_val_rand = a_val_rand + 1
        row_val_rand = randint(15, 34)
        count_val_rand = randint(15, 20)
        self.genLine_WObj(a_val_rand, b_val_rand, row_val_rand, 'm',
        count_val_rand)

        print 'Created mountains...'

        # Oceans:
        a_val_rand = choice([randint(5, 20), randint(20, 50)])
        b_val_rand = a_val_rand + 10
        row_val_rand = 34
        count_val_rand = randint(5, 15)
        self.genShiftBlock(a_val_rand, b_val_rand, row_val_rand, '~',
        count_val_rand)

        print 'Created oceans...'

        # Other:
        randCount = randint(2, 4)
        while randCount != 0:
            char_val_rand = choice(['D', 'V', '$']) # 'Dungeons', 'Village', 'Loot' icons.
            count_val_rand = randint(1, 4)
            self.genSingle_Char(char_val_rand, count_val_rand)
            randCount -= 1

        print 'Created random characters...'
        print 'Automatically modified world...'

    def manualModifyWorld(self):
        # The value 'world_object_type' is represented by
        # 'forest', 'mountain', 'ocean', or 'other'.
        for item in self.world_object_list:
            print item
        world_object_type = raw_input(
        ('What world object would you like to implement?: ').lower())
        a_val = input('Please specify value [a] of row_col_dict.: ')
        b_val = input('Please specify value [b] of row_col_dict: ')
        row_val = input('Please specify first row to be modified.: ')
        char_val = raw_input('Please specify char used to modify array.: ')
        count_val = input('Please specify number of times to repeat action: ')
        if world_object_type == 'forest':
            self.genLine_WObj(a_val, b_val, row_val, char_val, count_val)

        elif world_object_type == 'mountain':
            self.genLine_WObj(a_val, b_val, row_val, char_val, count_val)

        elif world_object_type == 'ocean':
            self.generateLineBlock(a_val, b_val, row_val, char_val, count_val)

        elif world_object_type == 'other':
            # 'other' is used to add single characters to the map.
            char_val = raw_input('Please specify char used to modify array.: ')
            count_val = input('Please specify times to repeat action: ')
            self.genSingle_Char(char_val, count_val)

        else:
            print 'Not a valid world object type!'

        repeat = input("""Would you like to reuse this function or continue?
1/ Yes, 2/ No.: """)
        print
        if repeat == 1:
            self.manualModifyWorld(False)

        elif repeat == 2:
            print 'Manually modified world...'
            pass

        while repeat not in [1, 2]:
            print 'Not a valid input.'
            repeat = input("""Would you like to reuse this function or continue?
    1/ Yes, 2/ No.: """)
            print

def main(player):
    print """
|[~~Welcome to the whiteWall world creator interface~~]|
"""
    auto = input('Would you like to automate this process?: 1/ Yes, 2/ No: ')
    if auto == 1:
        world = WorldSpace.generateWorld(True)
        world.autoModifyWorld()

    else:
        print """If you have already started a game, enter [1]. Otherwise, it is extremely
    important that you enter [2], so that a world space can be generated."""
        world_gen_inp = input("""
1. | Boot game?
2. | Generate new world?
> """)
        if world_gen_inp == 2:
            world = WorldSpace.generateWorld(False)
            print
            world.manualModifyWorld()

        else:
            pass

    print 'Now booting game...'
    # This section is a temporary solution.
    # In final version, this will loop to the main game loop.
    while player.baseStats['health'] != 0:
        print '##PLAYER MAP##'
        current_tile = world.world_array[player.x][player.y]
        world.world_array[player.x][player.y] = 'P'
        world.printPlayerMap()
        world.world_array[player.x][player.y] = current_tile
        print
        player.movement(world)

main(hero)
```

I'm looking for ways to cut down my code, or improve it in any way:

1. Creating a map of roughly 2000 x 2000 (or some other large amount) and only printing small sections of the maybe 30 or so tiles around the player at a time, based on their location on the map, to give the impression of a field of view and a nearly endless world.
2. If a player crosses a water `~`, or a mountain `m` tile, have them return to their previous position, to give the impression they cannot walk on certain tiles.

Answer (score 3):

Small suggestion, instead of:

```
if movement_inp == 'w':
    self.moveNorth()
elif movement_inp == 's':
    self.moveSouth()
elif movement_inp == 'd':
    self.moveEast()
elif movement_inp == 'a':
    self.moveWest()
else:
    print 'Not a valid command'
    self.movement(world)
```

Use:

```
movement = dict(w=self.moveNorth, s=self.moveSouth, d=self.moveEast, a=self.moveWest)
....
try:
    movement[movement_inp]()
except KeyError:
    print 'Not a valid command'
    self.movement()
```

Or better:

```
def __init__(self, x=0, y=0):
    self.directions = dict(w=(0,1), s=(0,-1), d=(1,0), a=(-1,0))
    ...

def movement(self):
    while True:
        movement_inp = raw_input("""
W. | Move North
S. | Move South
D. | Move East
A. | Move West
> """).lower()
        try:
            direction = self.directions[movement_inp]
        except KeyError:
            print 'Not a valid command'
        else:
            self.x, self.y = self.x + direction[0], self.y + direction[1]
            break
```

Which gets completely rid of the (very similar) `moveX` functions.

I also see no point in having `world` as a parameter when you don't do any checks with it.

While it is nice to abstract the skills part away a bit into different categories, it might be more advantageous to have them in the namespace directly. This way you could do `print "Strength: {.strength}".format(player)` or `player.strength += 5` on level up.